# Doubts in Knockout Validations

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Let me more clear.I am working in MVC application (MVC4) with knockout framework .I have totally 7 partial views showing in the same page for each partial views i am having seperate knockout viewmodel and binding it properly(without using master viewmodel, since everything is independent).until i moved to validation part everything moves great.I am struct in validations and posting the data.Here are the few questions in my head , i cant conclude the answers. Experts , please help to learn it.

1)i want to display the error message at diffrent place rather than showing it down.
i know we can use validationmessage attribute with that i can show with in the loop
(check fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/udp2z/5/) only.Is it posible to show anywhere apart from that?

2.how can i cumulate all the view model and send t to post. I have a button on the layout page - onclick of it i need to get all the view models as well as some of the non-knockout elements(getting it by using jquery).currently i can able to get all the viewmodels seperately.I want to make it as a single VM and send to the controller.

3.If i try to use knockuot vvalidtions how to get the total number of erros in the page( its there in the fiddler for the single viewmodel).how can i get the error count if i have more view models in the page.

4.If i want to go for jquery validation, kindly show me some tutorials.
Knockout validations from fiddler :

```
 <tr>
            <td colspan="4"> <span data-bind="validationMessage: Type"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SO finally here is the answers for the above.

1.NO, we can't display error message at custom location .It should be inside the databind location.say if i  bound data to tbody then the error message can be anywhere inside the tbody not event outside the tbody inside the table.

2.In my case i have created custom JSON and send it to server.

3 & 4 .I have created my own validations logic, you will have more control in this way